# Implementing unix command pipes in C. Problem with losing output

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork

I need to implement this command as C function:

```
ps -ef| tr -s ' '  :| cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c |sort n
```

I managed to get this to work until sort, which for some reason doesn't give me any output.
Here is my code:

```
void potok4()
{
  int pdesk1[2];
  int pdesk2[2];
  int pdesk3[2];
  int pdesk4[2];
  int pdesk5[2];

  pipe(pdesk1);
  pipe(pdesk2);
  pipe(pdesk3);
  pipe(pdesk4);
  pipe(pdesk5);

  if (pdesk1 < 0 || pdesk2 < 0 || pdesk3 < 0 || pdesk4 < 0 || pdesk5 < 0)
  {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (fork() == 0)
  {
    dup2(pdesk1[1], 1);
    close(pdesk1[0]);
    close(pdesk1[1]);
    execlp("ps", "ps", "-e", "-f", NULL);
    perror("ps");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (fork() == 0)
  {
    dup2(pdesk1[0], 0);
    dup2(pdesk2[1], 1);
    close(pdesk2[0]);
    close(pdesk2[1]);
    close(pdesk1[0]);
    close(pdesk1[1]);
    execlp("tr", "tr", "-s", " ", ":", NULL);
    perror("tr");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (fork() == 0)
  {
    dup2(pdesk2[0], 0);
    // if I comment line below, output seems fine
    dup2(pdesk3[1], 1);
    close(pdesk3[0]);
    close(pdesk3[1]);
    close(pdesk2[0]);
    close(pdesk2[1]);
    execlp("cut", "cut", "-d", ":", "-f", "1", NULL);
    perror("cut");
    exit(1);
  }
  close(pdesk3[1]);
  wait(NULL);
  if (fork() == 0)
  {
    dup2(pdesk3[0], 0);
    // but if I comment this
    // dup2(pdesk4[1], 1);
    close(pdesk4[0]);
    close(pdesk4[1]);
    close(pdesk3[0]);
    close(pdesk3[1]);
    //then this doesnt work
    execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);
    //this somehow works
    // execlp("head", "head", NULL);
    perror("sort");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (fork() == 0)
  {
    dup2(pdesk4[0], 0);
    dup2(pdesk5[1], 1);
    close(pdesk5[0]);
    close(pdesk5[1]);
    close(pdesk4[0]);
    close(pdesk4[1]);
    execlp("uniq", "uniq", "-c", NULL);
    perror("uniq");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (fork() == 0)
  {
    dup2(pdesk5[0], 0);
    close(pdesk5[0]);
    close(pdesk5[1]);
    execlp("sort", "sort", "-n", NULL);
    perror("sort -n");
    exit(1);
  }
  wait(NULL);
  exit(1);
}
```

As I wrote in comments, sort gives me no output and it seems like it waits for input (I can type in terminal when program is still running), but I don't understand why. I'm even more confused by the fact that somehow when I swap command for "head" I get expected result.

So what's the difference between

```
| sort
```

and

```
| head
```

that makes first one not work for me?
Second sort doesn't work too while uniq seems to work fine.

Comment: Off topic: note that `if (pdesk1 < 0 || pdesk2 < 0 || ...` doesn't check if any of the `pipe` calls failed -- which appears to be what you are expecting.

Comment: Yeah you're right, should be ```if( pipe(pdesk1) < 0)``` etc.